# Search Context in Domain Driven Design

Tags: domain-driven-design

How can a search context for website like stack overflow  be modelled following Domain driven design?

Let's say in my domain, I have three type of entities as Questions, Answers, Tags of Questions. 
I have to model a search context in a way that it accepts a search string and return matching questions, answers and tags.

I want to understand that, In search context, is search going to be just a ddd-service which will perform search or can there be some entities, aggregates etc.

It can be assumed that matching algorithm is simple sql like query.

Comment: I believe your question is too broad.  Can you be more specific? Perhaps provide some code and ask a specific question.

Comment: I am not sure what details to provide. My question is a bit broader, I want to understand top level classes in play for a search context. I have changed the description a bit, may be that might help or kindly suggest what details can I provide.

Comment: I think what you are asking for is the intellectual property of stack overflow.  There are plenty of good books on DDD.  Perhaps you could buy one if them? The concepts you learn can then be applied.

Comment: I am reading "Implementing Domain-driven Design Book by Vaughn Vernon", my doubt could not get cleared in the book, that's why I asked it here. I just wanted modelling of the search context as an example of implementing DDD.

Comment: I came across this question when trying to figure out how to apply DDD on eCommerce website for the 'explore' bounded context which comprises of browse-categories/search/filter/sort functionality. I am upvoting this since DDD on functional/algorithmic contexts does not have a lot of literature.

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement the search in a Query Service.

CQRS fits really good with DDD because when you want to update the model you use commands, such as in your case:

AnswerToQuestionCommand, PostNewQuestionCommand, etc.

These commands are sent to your application service, which updates the entity, which in turn send a DomainEvent, which is intercepted in the hexagonal architecture and updates the search index. You can do it in the hexagonal architecture: by calling a service dedicated to maintain the index in the same transaction. You consider an entity persisted if the index has also been updated for instance. I would go this way.

Here is a sample with Spring @TransactionalEventListener

```
@Component
public class ProjectRenamedListener {

    @Value("${spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.search.default.indexBase:target}")
    private String indexBase;

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProjectRenamedListener.class);

    @TransactionalEventListener
    public void projectRenamed(final ProjectRenamed event) {

        try (final StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
             final Directory directory = NIOFSDirectory.open(Paths.get(indexBase, ProjectData.class.getName()));
             final IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(directory, new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer))){

            final Document document = new Document();
            document.add(new StringField("project_id", event.projectId().identity(), Field.Store.YES));
            document.add(new StringField("tenant_id", event.tenant().identity(), Field.Store.YES));
            document.add(new TextField("name", event.name(), Field.Store.YES));
            writer.updateDocument(new Term("project_id", event.projectId().identity()), document);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.warn("Unable to update index for project name.", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

When you need to query your Questions, Answers, etc. you go through a query service. You ask the index, and load the entities that you want to return to your client.

The beauty of this is that it does not have to be the same object when you modify it and query it. It sounds a bit wierd when you start because of the code duplication but on the long run its clearly superior solution as you have no coupling between reading / query operation which occurs a lot and should be fast, and writing operation which should not occur a lot and does ont have to be specially super fast.

I would suggest the approach of Vaughn Vernon on query services (https://github.com/VaughnVernon/IDDD_Samples), I used lucene on my part for a query service, here is some code:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('Administrator')")
public Page<ProjectData> searchProjectsData(
        final String tenantId,
        final String queryText,
        final Pageable pageable) {

    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(tenantId)) {
        return this.searchProjectsDataOfTenant(tenantId, queryText, pageable);
    }

    final StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
    final QueryBuilder builder = new QueryBuilder(analyzer);
    final Query query = builder.createPhraseQuery("name", queryText);

    try {
        final IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.openIfChanged(this.directoryReader);
        final IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
        final TopDocs documents = searcher.search(query, pageable.getPageSize());
        return this.fetchProjectsData(searcher, documents, pageable);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Unable to search project for query: %s", queryText), e);
    }
}
```

Comment: EDIT: Added search maintening index in hexagonal architecture with a DomainEvent triggering the index update. Much better in term of DDD.

Comment: @sylvian-Lecoy so you mean, the 'writes' (command) bounded context now does not include indexes in its boundary, and hence not in transaction. Instead, it includes generation of a 'project renamed' DomainEvent as part of its transaction? And let the 'reads' (query) own the index and listen to the event and update its index in an 'eventually consistent' manner?

Comment: @jdhall yes that's exactly how it works. You nailed it ! In my case the eventually consistent manner is in the same bounded context because I've decided to put the query model a part of the same bounded context but you can totally outsource it. Fire an event in a Kafka architecture or rabbitmq and consuming it in the Search Bounded Context.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need the whole array of DDD tactical patterns for a Search bounded context, no. Except if you're planning on storing search preferences or creating search templates, maybe - even then, it seems very CRUDish.

Designing how the search context indexes or accesses the data from other BC's can be a more complex matter, though.

Comment: I was thinking that other BC's can emit events whenever a searchable entity is changed and search context can subscribe to those events to keep itself updated. Let's assume that we are not storing any preferences or templates. I am thinking that there can be an object called "searchRequest", which can contain data like "search query", "page number", "sorter", "applied filters" etc. Using which search repository(but only aggregates should have repositories) can produce search results. But what will this "seachRequest" object be,it is not entity(doesn't have identity). Is there any other way??

Comment: The event part is more or less what we do in my current team. The search service listens to those events, extracts interesting data and updates its internal Lucene index. As I was saying, you don't need to use the DDD patterns for the search service, so no Repository, no Entities, etc. As it is essentially a readonly context, you can take inspiration from what is done in CQRS with simple read models.

Comment: This article is a good read on DDD for writes and CQRS for reads: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/eshoponcontainers-cqrs-ddd-microservice